# Inline-block, Inline, Block

Tags: html, css

I've been searching about CSS lately, trying to teach myself the tricks.
One another issue I've encountered is directly related to the `display:` attribute.

I've been trying to get the width of the background element for my "menu buttons" as wide as the text they contain. The buttons are simply `<div>` elements.

When I use `display:block;` all of their width appear as wide as the longest item, and when I set it to `display:inline;` or `display:inline-block` they simply appear on the same line, just like how an inline element works.

Now, what I'm wondering is, how can I make them appear like a list, but still make the background color only as long as the text it contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want keep the format, have them wrap around the text and have a line for each item the inline-block or inline isn't an option. You'll have to use floats.

You can force each element on a seperate line by floating your items "float:left;" and forcing the floated elements on other lines with clear:both;

```
.item{
float:left;
clear:both;
}
```

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/Bn9Qx/

Answer (score 2):

Use a markup structure like this

```
<ul id="menu">
<!-- By the use of UL you can have the menu displayed as list -->
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    ...
</ul>
```

And apply the background CSS on the `#menu li a`

```css
#menu li a {
    /* a (anchor tag) is an inline tag, so the background 
    will span up to its content only */

    background: url("../src/to/img.jpg");
}
```

Comment: Oh that looks like a good solution, but, is there any way witout needing to change the hierarchy?
I can switch to 'ul' and 'li' items but creating a whole new system with href content will be a lot of work..

Comment: @Zettam, Since you want to apply the background to the content, you need an inline element or similar to make it behave like it.